# SQL Server 2008/2012/2016 - check if an object is system defined or user defined

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2008/2012/2016 how can I (most easily)
check if an object is system defined or user defined?

By object I mean e.g. a SP, a trigger, a UDF, or anything else.

I want to filter the system objects out of this query's results.
How do I do it? I looked around but didn't find an easy way.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME (id) as "schema", OBJECT_NAME(id) as "name", *   
FROM syscomments WHERE [text] LIKE '%raiserror%'
```

Comment: This query would give you all system objects - `select * from sys.objects where is_ms_shipped = 1`

Comment: @Abhishek Aha... so I just need to join to `sys.objects` and use the filter you suggest, right?

Comment: also filtery by `type <> 'S'` on `sys.objects` (system tables)

Comment: @peter.petrov - yup, you would be able to do it on the columns `id` and `object_id`. Just a note as per doc `syscomments` will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server and is suggested to use `sys.sql_modules`

Comment: Try adding `OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0` to where clause -- easier, portable (sql2000?) and fastest way to do it. Edit: ooops, same answer in linked duplicate :-))